# Java applet with expired signatures not working after selfsigning

Tags: java, dokuwiki

I am trying to re-sign a java applet that has expired signatures.

The applet is [Jdraw](http://www.hammurapi.com/products/jdraw/jdraw.zip), a plugin for Dokuwiki.

I have followed the instructions from other posts, and have created a keystore with my own keys, then I have unpacked the jars, I have repacked them and signed with my own signatures.

Now, the plugin installs fine but when I run it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mxgraph/swing/util/mxSwingConstants
    at com.hammurapi.jdraw.JDrawApplet.start(JDrawApplet.java:42)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mxgraph.swing.util.mxSwingConstants
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

com/mxgraph/swing/util/mxSwingConstants exists, in jgraphx.jar.

EDIT: I have tried adding CLASSPATH to manifest, but I still get the same error.

EDIT2:

This is what I added to manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Application-Name: jdraw
Class-Path: jgraphx.jar
```

Comment: Is jgraphx.jar not part of the applet? I think you need to unpack the jgraphx.jar and also add it to the applet.

Comment: yes, I have unpacked all the jars (8) in the applet with jar xvf name.jar, I have removed META-INF, repacked them with jar cvf name.jar and I have signed them again.

Comment: Ok, if you have compared that the folder structures are the same I don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did not change the folder structure at all. Still the original plugin is not working because of the certificate, so I cannot know if the original code has issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take all the original jars(all the jars in the applet classpath before you singned the applet), **fix the exception** and then sign them with the new cert; note that files already signed will not work, you need to use the jars without any signature.
**Fix the exception** ClassNotFoundException by adding jgraphx.jar to the classpath of your applet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that self-signed applets are no longer accepted by any of the major
browsers.  You have to buy a cert if you want to operate as an applet.

Comment: I have added the dokuwiki server as an exception, and I have lowered the security settings as much as possible. This resulted in bypassing/tricking the self-signed security limitation. Now I cannot make the plugin work because of the classpath issue.

Comment: I suspect that your code is using the same techniques that java exploits use to escape the sandbox, and you're being caught up in security "fixes".   Try changing your java permissions to all-permissions instead of sandbox.

Comment: I have added to manifest the permissions you mention (I have edited the post to show that better). I take it the plugin was badly written and it wont work without some heavy rewriting.

Comment: Don't be too harsh; "badly written" is a moving target.